# python: one-liner for 'if list[0] == "foo"' when list might be empty

Tags: python

I really hate to write this inside loops and ifs:

```
if len(list) != 0: #or just "if list:", but explicit better than implicit
    if list[0] == "foo":
        ...
```

What's your favorite one-liner (or one nesting level at least) analogue for that?

EDIT: Sorry, this is a dumb question of mine, I glitched here. But I feel that there were cases, when two conditions in `if a and/or b` will cause exception if written together but can be True all together nonetheless. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `if len(list) != 0 and list[0] == "foo": ...`?

Comment: I don't think the "explicit is better than implicit" rule applies here; `if somelist:` is a standard idiom for testing nonemptiness. We don't write `if bool(somecondition) is True:`, we write `if somecondition:`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if list and list[0] == 'foo':
    ....
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, my brain glitched. Thanks. I really feel, that I had some cases when two conditions I check can result in True, but together cause an exception.

Comment: In Python, `and` does "short-circuit" evaluation, so if `list` evaluates false, `list[0]` won't be evaluated.  By the way, it's bad practice to use `list` as a variable name; suggested abbreviations include `lst` or `L`.  If you use `list` as a variable then you "shadow" the `list` class.  (You can still access it using tricks like `type([])` but it's easier to just not hide it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make sure that foo is in the list, you can use:

```
if 'foo' in my_list:
    do_something()
```

Otherwise, if index 0 of the list needs to be foo, I would use:

```
if my_list and my_list[0] == 'foo':
    do_something()
```